# Can I make a bootable USB stick boot on both a PC and a Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple

So, I already have a 64-bit 16.04 LTS installed on a USB stick. That already works and boots successfully on any PC or PC laptop.

What I'm interested in is to know if and how, you can make the SAME usb installation to also boot on a Mac (Macbook Pro 2015, Intel i5 CPU). When I try to boot with it (by holding the Option down while booting the Mac), the Mac doesn't recognize it as bootable, it only gives me the option to boot the MacOS X drive.

So, I wonder if there are any packages that I can install, that will make an *existing* installation to ALSO boot on the Mac, in addition to the PC(s). Thx!

EDIT: I should add, all of my PCs are non-EFI (they're plain BIOS). I know that the Macbook is EFI. Is there a way to have the same bootable USB stick boot on both on EFI and BIOS PCs/Macs?

Answer (score 0):

### USB boot stick 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu'

Yes, the same USB boot stick works in modern Mac computers with Intel processors as in 'standard PCs made for Windows and linux'. You should use a 64-bit iso file (with *amd64* in the file name).

If there are difficulties, they are of the same kind, that you might have with a 'standard' PC, for example with the UEFI boot system or with drivers for graphics or wifi. There is an [Ubuntu Forum for Mac computers](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328).

### Ubuntu installed to a USB stick (like into an internal drive)

During the installation, the installed system will be locked into either UEFI or BIOS (the mode you are running during the installation), unless you do some special tricks,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS)

but I don't know if it works in a Mac computer (if the correct drivers are installed).

A compromise is to use a persistent live system, which can be made according to this link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

Comment: Yes, only it doesn't see it as bootable. I'm guessing there's something I need to tweak. Just don't know what.

Comment: I suggest that you browse this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=328, and if necessary you can ask there, where you can get help in a longer dialogue. (Here at AskUbuntu  it is expected to be well defined questions and answers.)

Comment: Thanks. I added some more info on the question above, to narrow down the question. I will check that forum, although it's yet another account I need to make...

Comment: 64-bit iso files with *amd64* in the file name work in both UEFI and BIOS mode, but 32-bit iso files work only in BIOS mode (unless you use some special tricks).

Comment: Mine is 64bit, thx.

Comment: There are several help pages to be found via the internet, for example this one:  http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-install-linux-on-mac-3637265/

Comment: That tutorial does not answer my question. I don't want to create a new installation. The real question I was asking is I guess, if I upgrade my BIOS-based USB installation to UEFI, if both EFI and BIOS PCs will boot from it. I want ONE installation on a USB stick, for all of my Intel computers.

Comment: You wrote that you made your USB boot drive from a 64-bit iso file. It works in both UEFI and BIOS mode, at least when installed into the USB drive with the cloning method (with *Disks* or *mkusb*). I am 100% sure because I am testing iso files before they are released, and I test in both UEFI and BIOS mode. But I have no Mac computer. I cannot help with the fine details, that you must tweak correctly. This is why I suggest that you start an own thread in the Ubuntu Forum for Mac computers, where you can discuss and get help from people who run Ubuntu in Mac computers.

Comment: After reading your question once again, I have to ask: is this an installed system in a USB drive (installed like into an internal drive) as opposed to a live drive or persistent iive drive, where you can *Try Ubuntu* or *Install Ubuntu*? In that case it can be very tricky to make a system that boots both in UEFI and BIOS mode. I describe such a system in this link: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS, but I don't know if it works in a Mac computer (if the correct drivers are installed).

Comment: It's indeed an installed system on a USB drive, not a "live try-out" thing. It was installed on /dev/sda1 under a BIOS-based laptop, using the amd64 iso.

Comment: I see, and my answers have been assuming they were "live try-out" things. Anyway, during the installation, the installed system will be locked into either UEFI or BIOS (the mode you are running during the installation), unless you do some special tricks. A compromise is to use a *persistent live* system, which can be made according to this link:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent